What is docker compose waiting for?
When I start up my docker compose project all services quickly jump to the 'status' Started which seems normal (docker compose up -d --build). However I have one service which stays in Waiting forever.
However when I look at the output of docker ps it shows the service in the Up state (like all the others) and I can also look that the logs and they show what I expect.
Now I am confused what the status shown by the docker up -d command really indicates and what it is dependent on so I can further investigate my problem. I have not found anything specific in the docs yet and also my investigations have been unsuccessful so far (I tried adding a health-check).
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           27.0.3
 API version:       1.46
 Go version:        go1.21.11
 Git commit:        7d4bcd8
 Built:             Sat Jun 29 00:02:33 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          27.0.3
  API version:      1.46 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.11
  Git commit:       662f78c
  Built:            Sat Jun 29 00:02:33 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     true
 containerd:
  Version:          1.7.18
  GitCommit:        ae71819c4f5e67bb4d5ae76a6b735f29cc25774e
 runc:
  Version:          1.7.18
  GitCommit:        v1.1.13-0-g58aa920
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version v2.28.1



In my case it turned out that I had another service depending on the service finishing that was stuck in waiting
...
   depends_on:
      xxx:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

So the status indication seems to also monitor specified dependencies and not only if the service started as I assumed
